# Skipping empty lines in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm working with a fortran code, where my input file looks something like this:

```
...
Binning n:    4, "Si2-Events",  Event #:            12, Primary(s) weight  1.0000E+00
    Number of hit cells:           3
      488534  4.23038400E-05      489533  1.50734719E-04      489534  5.79968946E-05

   Binning n:    4, "Si2-Events",  Event #:            13, Primary(s) weight  1.0000E+00
    Number of hit cells:           2
      477500  3.04398331E-04      478500  1.13192732E-06

   Binning n:    4, "Si2-Events",  Event #:            14, Primary(s) weight  1.0000E+00
    Number of hit cells:           2
      512496  1.32522946E-05      513496  2.86743394E-04

   Binning n:    4, "Si2-Events",  Event #:            15, Primary(s) weight  1.0000E+00
    Number of hit cells:           2
      476539  1.95245666E-04      476540  2.37216373E-05

   Binning n:    4, "Si2-Events",  Event #:            16, Primary(s) weight  1.0000E+00
    Number of hit cells:           9
      502533  1.26090490E-05      502534  1.00212252E-04      503527  3.07000097E-04      503528  9.53662311E-06      503529  9.42530642E-06      503530  1.07992764E-05      503531  1.26466557E-05      503532  1.68176994E-05      503533  1.18242851E-05
...
```

In other words, I have a file with many many lines, each displaying a cell number and energy in the third row, e.g.

```
488534  4.23038400E-05      489533  1.50734719E-04      489534  5.79968946E-05
```

I want to write a fortran code that reads only this line, and writes to an output file the cell number and energy in two colums, something like

```
Line             1                    

Cells   488534
        489533
        489534

Energy
 4.23038400E-05
 1.50734719E-04
 5.79968946E-05


Line 2 

Cells     477500  
          478500  

Energy  3.04398331E-04
         1.13192732E-06


etc...
```

The problem is that the number of cells varies from line to line. 
How can I make it skip to the next line when it has read all the values?

Here is a little bit of the code I tested out:

```
open (unit=7, file="Si1.txt", action="read", access="sequential")


open (unit=8, file="output.txt", action="write")

do i = 1, 900


    read (7,*) line1
    read (7,*) line2
    read (7,*) cell1, energy1, cell2, energy2
    write(8,*) "Run = ", i, "and cells = ", cell1, cell2, "and energy = ", energy1, energy2
end do
```

Problem is that this only worked as long as there was two or more values in that row, and not if it was less than two.

I'm a bit lost (and possibly a noob here), but any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

You're currently ignoring the useful information on the 2nd line of each block, *ie* the number of cell number/energy pairs to be found on the 3rd line of the block.  So get that information.

Replace your

```
read(7,*) line2
```

by a statement such as

```
 read(7,'(a32,i)') words, num_cells
```

I write 'such as' because I haven't counted how many characters to read into the `words` variable (which you will have declared as `character(len=32) :: words` or similar), you'll have to do that for yourself.  Following execution of this statement the integer variable `num_cells` will have the number of cell pairs to read from the next line.  Replace your

```
read (7,*) cell1, energy1, cell2, energy2
```

with

```
do ix = 1, num_cells
   read (7,fmt=*, advance='no') cell(ix), energy(ix)
end do
read (7, '()', advance = ’yes’)
```

The `advance=no` argument tells the processor not to move to the next line in the input file after reading the cell/energy pair.  The line at the end of the loop, on the other hand, tells the processor to move to the next line.

Obviously (?) I haven't written you a complete solution but you should be able to take it the rest of the way.  And I haven't tested this for you, so there may well be minor errors with the syntax.